# last checkout time on a svn repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to check the last checkout time of developers on a svn repository (something like an admin command). Would like to track on usage patterns related to frequency of checkout.

Comment: @tagger: this is not specific to tortoisesvn.

Comment: We use tortoisesvn also, hence I thought there could be something if we use this tool, hence the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) gives you this and many more metrics.  For example:

> StatSVN retrieves information from a
>   Subversion repository and generates
>   various tables and charts describing
>   the project development, e.g. timeline
>   for the lines of code, contribution of
>   each developer etc. The current
>   version of StatSVN generates a static
>   suite of HTML or XDOC documents
>   containing tables and chart images.

Feature list:
•Lines of code (LOC) metrics per commit, author, directory, and file.
•Commit history
•LOC evolution graph, activity by date and time of day
•Web repository integration (ViewVC, Chora, Trac)
•Bug tracker integration (Bugzilla, Mantis)
•Apache Ant task
•Generate HTML, XML, XDOC
•Concurrently query server to obtain lines of code changed/added, per file, per commit
•Works with multiple branches
•Basic support for copy/renames
•Support for tags
•Can anonymizes committer names

Comment: will give this a try sometime tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Apache to produce specific SVN logs.
See the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging) on how to do that and what that log contains.

Comment: Apache log (1.6) http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging

Answer (score 0):

use a svn "checkout hook" ?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.html - pre checkout hooks are missing here, is there any other way to do this

Comment: Checkout hook (1.6) http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks